# Prettier and eslint indents not working together

Tags: javascript, typescript, vim, eslint, prettier

I traying setup my vim based typescript developing environment, but have an issue with indent management.

[image]

Probably 'eslint' says: `indent: Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4.` after `prettier` reformat.

My `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = { 
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  extends: [ 
    'plugin:react/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: { 
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    ecmaFeatures: { 
      jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
      tsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of TSX ???
    },
  },
  rules: { 
    indent: ['error', 2],
    quotes: ['error', 'single'],
    semi: ['error', 'never'],
    'sort-keys': ['error', 'asc', { caseSensitive: true, natural: false }],
  },
}
```

My `.prettierc`:

```
 module.exports = { 
  semi: false,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 80, 
  tabWidth: 2,
};
```

Comment: Same problem here! All the linters and auto formatting options conflict with each other! I couldn’t get code without a semicolon be accepted without errors... I had to resort to just using vs code’s native auto formatting 

Answer (score 50):

As per this Kai Cataldo's comment on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10930):

> ESLint's indent rule and Prettier's indentation styles do not match - they're completely separate implementations and are two different approaches to solving the same problem ("how do we enforce consistent indentation in a project").

Therefore, when using `prettier`, you'd better disable eslint's `indent` rule. It's guaranteed that they will clash.

Comment: I didn't realize I had an old hangover `indent` rule in my eslint config, thanks!

Comment: disabling `indent` rule is not an option if you want to keep a linter

Answer (score 28):

This should fix it [https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#installation)

It disables rules in eslint that conflict with prettier.

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier
```

in your `.eslintrc.*` file put last "prettier" to `extends` section

```
"extends": [
         //"some-other-config-you-use",
         "prettier"
      ],
```

Comment: To add to this, make sure to add this LAST in the extensions list so it overrides other eslint rules!

Comment: Moving `plugins` under `rules` does the work!

Answer (score 17):

in `eslintrc` add `indent: [2, 2, { SwitchCase: 1}]`

Parameters defined

1. new eslint rules want the first parameter to be a number: `Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error`.
2. the amount of indent
3. The object is stating how to indent `switch` and `case` statements following the [options here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#options).

Comment: any idea what is happening here?

Comment: @itsmnthn Did [clay's edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65619058/2) answer your question?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue. Thing is you can just manually override any clashing rules. In my case it was the `prettier/prettier` plugin for ESLint, so that can be solved adding the indent rule, under the required plugin.

```
"rules": {
        // "indent":["error",10]
        "prettier/prettier":[  //or whatever plugin that is causing the clash
            "error",
            {
                "tabWidth":4
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can override specific rules like this, to get rid of any clashes.

Answer (score 9):

Turning off default Visual Studio Code parser and just leaving the eslint parser on save fixed it for me.

Just go to settings `Ctrl/Cmd + ,`, choose `User` (global settings) or `Workspace` (only for the working repo) and on top right corner click the paper with a turning arrow. That will open the declared settings on a json file. With the following settings it should work on any case:

```json
{
  // other settings
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.organizeImports": false
  },
  // other settings
}
```

Normally at the bottom of the Visual Studio Code window you have a `Fix on save: X` flag. That should be linked with this setting so make sure to leave it consistent.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question which is about vim and not VSCode

Comment: This was my issue. Even though I had `indent: 0` in my eslint config and was using eslint-config-prettier, I was getting conflicting formatting with ternary operators in JSX. I had no idea that VS Code had its own parser on top of eslint.

Answer (score 4):

1. **eslint-config-prettier will disable all ESLint formatting rules that may conflict with Prettier's rules**.
   `npm i --save-dev eslint-config-prettier`
2. eslint-plugin-prettier is the plugin that will add Prettier's formatting rules.
3. Let's tell ESLint we'll use Prettier's recommended configuration:
   `npm i --save-dev eslint-plugin-prettier`

```
//eslintrc.js
{
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most annoying thing.. so fixed with: `eslint-config-prettier`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-tabs": ["error", {"allowIndentationTabs": true}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems on my end, the only conflict is with ternary operations. Another option to fix the issue is to use the following eslint rule.

```
"indent": ["error", 2, { "offsetTernaryExpressions": true }],
```

There are a lot more options here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent#offsetternaryexpressions

I find eslint's indent rules more configurable and would use them over prettier.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what I did was I removed the indentation rule from the ***.eslintrc*** file and added `useTabs: true` to my ***.prettierrc*** file.

[image]

After reloading the VS Code it works perfectly with the tab size indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and by changing Prettier to Use Tabs in the settings menu (ctrl + shift + P), it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, and thanks for posting an answer. However, it would be much better if you actually explain steps. Your one sentence here is not enough to help me fix my problem. I'm confused about what you're saying.

Comment: This is a simple single settings change, there is but one step. Since I've been on StackExchange for 8+ years, I find your comment a bit condescending.

Comment: My apologies. I wasn't trying to be condescending.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just changed **CRLF** (Carriage Return, Line Feed) to **LF** (Line Feed) on VSCode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS-Code and configured the `eslint` and `prettier` settings as per the others answers here, then also check this option in VS-Code ;)

Change it to 'Tab' instead.

[image: VS-Code Tab Options]

Answer (score 0):

So, `npm i --save-dev eslint-config-prettier` fixed the Issue as pointed out by [Akshay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761641/akshay-vijay-jain)